# Hide html when submit button clicked, echo results staying on same page, email form results EXAMPLE PROVIDED

Tags: php, html, forms, email, session

I searched for a basic explanation and example on how to hide my html form "onsubmit" with basic php, while staying on the same page. I also needed to email the form results. I found bits here and there usually complicated and outside of my beginner abilities. So I am going to share a basic example of what I think is the easiest way to obtain this.

HTML Form with php:

```
<?php
session_start();
//if you require login start session first thing at top

?>
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


</script>

</head>

<title>Example Form </title>

<?php

//my database connection is in insert.php

include_once 'insert.php';

//Set up email to receive the desired form results

$submit = $_POST['submit'];

$to = "youremail@yourdomain.com";
$email = "youremail@yourdomain.com";
$user = $_SESSION['yoursession']; #this is if require user login
$companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
$companyurl = $_POST['companyurl'];
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; #capture user's ip address
$subject = $companyname;

if(isset($submit) && !empty($companyname || $companyurl)){


$headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
//$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender

$body = "

Company Name: $companyname \n\n Company URL: $companyurl \n\n User IP Address: $ipaddressadvertise

";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){

//What will show after submit button selected...

echo "Successfully submitted!" . "<br />";

echo "<br />" . "<strong>Company Name:  </strong>  " . "&nbsp;" . "$companyname" . "<br />" . "<strong>Company Website:  </strong>  " . "&nbsp;" . "$companyurl" . "<br />";
}else {

    echo "Oops something went wrong. Try again or come back later. " . "<br />";

}
}
?>

<body>

<?php

//This is where you start to wrap what you want to hide onsubmit.

$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if(!isset($submit)){

//Do NOT put closing curly brace leave open and see below.

?>


<form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>


<table border="0">

<tr>Company Name: <align = "center"><input type = "text" id = "companyname" name = "companyname" value = "" placeholder = "Required" required><br /><br />

<tr>Company Website: <align = "center"><input type = "text" id = "companyurl" name = "companyurl" value = "" placeholder = "Required" required><br /><br />


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick = "location.href='mailto:youremail@yourdomain.com';" value="Submit!">

<tr></tr><br /><br />
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>

</form>

<?php

  } //This is where you put your closing curly brace wrapping all of the information you want to hide when submit button is clicked.

?>
</body>
</html>
```

When the submit button is clicked the form should disappear, the message displays staying on the same page (without re-direct to another page) while emailing you the results.

NOTE: I tried this in the snippet and it didn't work. But I loaded it to a live site and it works perfectly without errors.

Comment: Where did you learn about the `<align="center">` tag?

Comment: @Script47 I believe W3schools online. They are an excellent source for beginners.

Comment: Can you provide a link or tell me how you got to that page? BTW, expect to get quoted w3fools or some other mocking term if people get wind of your comment.

Comment: @Script47 I have thick skin. I am a beginner and the site helped me to build confidence to proceed to learn further. But thanks for the heads up. There are multiple references in their site. Simply search their site for the align tag. I don't think their is anything dedicated to it, specifically. And it looks like I did not use it properly here. oops. Thank you for pointing to it. I am removing it, for now.

Answer (score 1):

A basic structure can be something like that:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))  {   // if submit - send email
    $you = "YOUREMAIL";
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
    mail($you, $subject, $comment, "From:" . $email);   //send email
    echo "Thank you for contacting us!";    //Email response
  }


  else  {   // else display the form:
?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
      <label for="email">Email: 
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" />
      </label>
      <label for="subject">Subject: 
        <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" />
      </label>
      <label for="comment">Comment:
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php  } ?>
```