# Attempting to use if !isset to display results without the form

Tags: php, forms

I am attempting to display the results without the form being shown at the same time.   So, initially when they go to the URL they see the form, and after they fill out the form and the form validation and required fields and URL is valid.  Here is what I started with.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$TXTlinknameErr = $TXTurlErr = "";
$TXTlinkname = $TXTurl = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["TXTlinkname"])) {
    $TXTlinknameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $TXTlinkname = test_input($_POST["TXTlinkname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$TXTlinkname)) {
      $TXTlinknameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["TXTurl"])) {
    $TXTurl = "";
  } else {
    $TXTurl = test_input($_POST["TXTurl"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$TXTurl)) {
      $TXTurlErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["TXTurl"])) {
    $TXTurlErr = "URL is required";
  } else {
    $TXTurl = test_input($_POST["TXTurl"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Create HTML Link</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="TXTlinkname" value="<?php echo $TXTlinkname;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $TXTlinknameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  URL: <input type="text" name="TXTurl" value="<?php echo $TXTurl;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $TXTurlErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your HTML Code:</h2>";
echo "<br>";
echo '<textarea name="htmlcode" rows="10" cols="60"><a href="' . $TXTurl . '" target="_new">' . $TXTlinkname . '</a></textarea>';


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I have tried.

I've tried adding else statements after body and before results.  I'd like the results not to show until after form submitted.
Here's what I have so far...

I tried to add the below after the body

```
<?php
//If form not submitted, display form.
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])||(($_POST['name']) == "")){
?>
```

Then I added:

```
<?php 

} else {
//Retrieve show string from form submission.
```

Just after

```
// define variables and set to empty values
```

Finally added:

```
<?php

} ?>
```

Before /body

Here is what I tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  
    <?php
    //If form not submitted, display form.
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])||(($_POST['TXTlinkname'] && $_POST['TXTurl']) == "")){
    ?> 
    <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$TXTlinknameErr = $TXTurlErr = "";
$TXTlinkname = $TXTurl = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["TXTlinkname"])) {
    $TXTlinknameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $TXTlinkname = HTML_input($_POST["TXTlinkname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$TXTlinkname)) {
      $TXTlinknameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["TXTurl"])) {
    $TXTurl = "";
  } else {
    $TXTurl = HTML_input($_POST["TXTurl"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$TXTurl)) {
      $TXTurlErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["TXTurl"])) {
    $TXTurlErr = "URL is required";
  } else {
    $TXTurl = HTML_input($_POST["TXTurl"]);
  }
}

function HTML_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Create HTML Link</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="TXTlinkname" value="<?php echo $TXTlinkname;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $TXTlinknameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  URL: <input type="text" name="TXTurl" value="<?php echo $TXTurl;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $TXTurlErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
} else {
echo "<h2>Your HTML Code:</h2>";
echo "<br>";
echo '<textarea name="htmlcode" rows="10" cols="60"><a href="' . $TXTurl . '" target="_new">' . $TXTlinkname . '</a></textarea>';
?>
    <button onclick="location = location.href">Go Back</button>
<?php

} ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

So, initially when they go to the URL they see the form, and after they fill out the form and the form validation and required fields and URL is valid.

Comment: maybe try just  if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){

Comment: Check this for basic structure https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917983/6525081

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: @JD Sorry but not getting what you exactly want to do.

Comment: As of now, it is showing the form when I hit the page and once submitted and pass the validation then it shows the textarea with Go back button. Also, there are 2 PHP notices in your else condition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a variable that tells you if you're going to show the textarea or not...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$TXTlinknameErr = $TXTurlErr = "";
$TXTlinkname = $TXTurl = "";

$show_textarea = false; //DEFAULT
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //The form is sent...
    $show_textarea = true; //Then this is DEFAULT!!
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["TXTlinkname"])) {
    $show_textarea = false; //DON'T SHOW TEXTAREA
    $TXTlinknameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {

    $TXTlinkname = test_input($_POST["TXTlinkname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$TXTlinkname)) {
      $show_textarea = false; //DON'T SHOW TEXTAREA 
      $TXTlinknameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["TXTurl"])) {
    $show_textarea = false; //DON'T SHOW TEXTAREA
    $TXTurl = "";
  } else {
    $TXTurl = test_input($_POST["TXTurl"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$TXTurl)) {
      $show_textarea = false; //DON'T SHOW TEXTAREA
      $TXTurlErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["TXTurl"])) {
    $show_textarea = false; //DON'T SHOW TEXTAREA
    $TXTurlErr = "URL is required";
  } else {
    $TXTurl = test_input($_POST["TXTurl"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


if ($show_textarea === false) {
?>
<h2>Create HTML Link</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="TXTlinkname" value="<?php echo $TXTlinkname;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $TXTlinknameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  URL: <input type="text" name="TXTurl" value="<?php echo $TXTurl;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $TXTurlErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>    
<?php
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //The form is sent...
    if ($show_textarea === true ) { //...AND the form has valid values
        echo "<h2>Your HTML Code:</h2>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo '<textarea name="htmlcode" rows="10" cols="60">
        <a href="' . $TXTurl . '" target="_new">' . $TXTlinkname . '</a> 
        </textarea>';
    }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I tried it, but it displays the textarea even if it doesn't pass validation.

Comment: aha I did not understand your question correctly... wait I'll update soon.

Comment: I updated my answer now. I hope it was what you were looking for.

Comment: Updated again. It's just basically to do a if-condition when to show the form.

Comment: The updated code did not work...  If fields are empty it goes to the textarea, but if the form is filled out it doesn't.  The  one you had up before  was the closest but it shows the form and results on the same page.  I only wanted the results (textarea) to show if form successfully submitted and clears validation.

Comment: Sorry about that. I think it would work as you would expect now. BUT there could absolety be improvements in the code.

Comment: PERFECT!  YOU ARE THE bestprogrammerintheworld FOR SHIZZLE BIZZLE!  
I am open to suggestions to improve it.  What would be better?

Comment: I missed an issue...  It printing the HTML code textarea if the TXTlinkname field is empty...

Comment: For clarification....  If both TXTlinkname and TXTurl are empty the TXTlinknameErr shows, but if put a URL in TXTurl and leave TXTlinkname  emtpy the TXTlinknameErr does not show...

Comment: I do love this solution, but still having issues with when both TXTlinkname and TXTurl are empty the TXTlinknameErr shows, but if put a URL in TXTurl and leave TXTlinkname emtpy the TXTlinknameErr does not show

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to answer this within a week In sorry

Comment: No worries.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you sort it out?

Comment: You have to put show_textarea to false on both textfields when they are empty! :-) Sorry for late update... !

Answer (score 0):

The big issue I see with your code is the if statement. The variables are not defined unless form hasn't been submitted. What I've changed is moved the function to be defined globally along with the variable names, and inverted the if statement. PHP Tags, you don't need them everywhere. One wrapper is good enough.

I'm not sure about what your result is, but for what you asked, I shall provide.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php
            function HTML_input($data) {
              $data = trim($data);
              $data = stripslashes($data);
              $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
              return $data;
            }

            $TXTlinkname = $TXTurl = "";
            $TXTlinknameErr = $TXTurlErr = "";
            //If form not submitted, display form.
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if (empty($_POST['TXTurl'])) {
                    $TXTurlErr = "URL is required";
                } else {
                    $TXTurl = HTML_input($_POST['TXTurl']);
                    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
                    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$TXTurl)) {
                        $TXTurlErr = "Invalid URL"; 
                    }
                }

                if (empty($_POST['TXTname'])) {
                    $TXTlinknameErr = "Name is required";
                } else {
                    $TXTlinkname = HTML_input($_POST['TXTname']);
                    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$TXTlinkname)) {
                        $TXTlinknameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                    }
                }
            }

            if (empty($TXTurlErr) && empty($TXTlinknameErr) && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                echo "<h2>Your HTML Code:</h2>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo '<textarea name="htmlcode" rows="10" cols="60"><a href="' . $TXTurl . '" target="_new">' . $TXTlinkname . '</a></textarea>';
                echo '<button onclick="location = location.href">Go Back</button>';
            } else {
                echo '<h2>Create HTML Link</h2>
                <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
                <form method="post" action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'">  
                  Name: <input type="text" name="TXTname" value="'.$TXTlinkname.'">
                  <span class="error">* '. $TXTlinknameErr .'</span>
                  <br><br>
                  URL: <input type="text" name="TXTurl" value="'.$TXTurl.'">
                  <span class="error">'.$TXTurlErr.'</span>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
                </form>';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tested locally on XAMPP

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion and feedback, @SeaWorld...   If the fields are emply or    invalid TXTlinknameErr, $TXTlinknameErr do not show.  Also i it still returns the textarea if not validated

Comment: It works almost perfect...  except if you just go to the form URL to start.  Then it shows the header and the closing body and html tags.

Comment: Missed the boat, but fixed it anyways :)

Answer (score -3):

try this one:

```
if (!$_POST) || $_POST['TXTlinkname'] == "" && $_POST['TXTurl']) == "")){
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, and Getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR)   on line 11

Comment: You are not closing the brackets correctly. Please check your code before posting it. It breaks the things for other users.

Comment: I am new to php.  Could you tell me where the brackets are incorrect, and how I can correct?